# Is it possible to restore a Redshift cluster to another VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to move an existing Redshift database from one AWS account to another following [How do I transfer ownership of an Amazon Redshift cluster to a different AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-redshift/). I've successfully created a snapshot of the old database and given the new account access to it. Both accounts have different VPCs.

When I try to restore a cluster from that snapshot, I receive the following error message:

```
You have no subnet groups that are suitable for restoring this snapshot to VPC.
```

Is it possible to restore a Redshift cluster to another VPC? I can't create a Subnet to the old VPC since it's in my new AWS account.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an Amazon Redshift Cluster Subnet Group, which is a list of subnets that Redshift can use within a particular VPC.

In the Amazon Redshift management console:

- Click **Security** in the left navigation pane
- Click the **Subnet Groups** tab
- Create a **Subnet Cluster Group** by choosing a VPC, AZ(s) and subnet(s)

Then, try restoring the snapshot again and select your new Subnet Cluster Group.

Comment: I am asking this question after 3 years of your post but wanted to know, if I have data in my redshift and its in subnet 1, and i want to move it to subnet 2 within the same VPC, does the data retention happen automatically or I will have to take backup of data and then again push it to redshift. Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: @mr.cool Please create a new question rather than asking a question in a comment in an existing question.

Comment: I raised a new question. can you please take a look. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036250/move-redshift-from-subnet-1-to-subnet-2-within-the-same-vpc]. Thanks