# Restore Redshift snapshot to another VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Redshift newbie question.

From [Managing Clusters in an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-clusters-vpc.html):

> You can restore it [a snapshot] in the same VPC or another VPC in your account.

When I go to restore a snapshot, I see options for restoring to a different subnet group *within* the VPC, but no option for selecting a different VPC altogether.  (The VPCs are under the same account.)

I did see this question [Is it possible to restore a Redshift cluster to another VPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570731/is-it-possible-to-restore-a-redshift-cluster-to-another-vpc) but it is about transferring across accounts and addressing a specific error message.

Comment: Hey, but did you tried what the answer says? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32575392/97471

Comment: The answer in the question Gerardo linked is the correct answer. This question is an exact duplicate of that question.

Comment: Thank you it was not obvious to me at first that selecting a subnet group is implicitly selecting a VPC as well.  I say "not obvious" because when you first create the cluster there are separate dropdowns for VPC and subnet group, but on restore, there is no separate select for VPC.