# Move Redshift from Subnet 1 to Subnet 2 within the same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a VPC which has 2 Private subnets i.e. subnet 1 and subnet 2. My redshift cluster sits in subnet 2 and has data. I want to move the redshift from subnet 2 to subnet 1 within the same VPC (Which can be done easily). But I have few doubts related to data migration:

1. Does data migration happens automatically without any data loss or do I need to take the backup, create the cluster in subnet 1 and then again push the backed up data to the cluster.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From [Amazon Redshift Snapshots - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html):

> **Restoring a Cluster from a Snapshot**
>
> A snapshot contains data from any databases that are running on your cluster, and also information about your cluster, including the number of nodes, node type, and master user name. If you need to restore your cluster from a snapshot, Amazon Redshift uses the cluster information to create a new cluster and then restores all the databases from the snapshot data. The new cluster that Amazon Redshift creates from the snapshot will have same configuration, including the number and type of nodes, as the original cluster from which the snapshot was taken. **The cluster is restored in the same region and a random, system-chosen Availability Zone, unless you specify another Availability Zone in your request.**

So, you should take a Snapshot of the existing Redshift cluster, then create a new cluster in the other AZ by Restoring a Cluster from the Snapshot. Once everything seems to be okay, you can delete the old cluster.

Comment: Yeah we can do this but the problem is I am using cloudformation for the creation of stack. So if I restore the cluster in subnet 2, the stack name will be different and when I again try to create the stack using CF, it will spin off a new cluster.

Comment: So, are you saying that the Redshift cluster was deployed by CloudFormation? To move the cluster, you would need to effectively disconnect Redshift from the stack, because it will not keep the data while changing the AZ.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. Cannot find any workaround to get the data back in the new AZ.

Comment: Correct. You should also be careful -- unless you have defined a Deletion Policy, then the Redshift cluster will be deleted when the CloudFormation stack is deleted. It would be advisable to turn on Termination Protection for the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but looking at the comments in the other answer I ran into the same issue.  To move from one subnet to another you do the following:

1. Make sure your subnet group has both subnets in it
2. Take a snapshot of the current cluster
3. Restore the snapshot to a new cluster using the same settings as the original cluster but select the other AZ that you want it to be in.  Name the cluster something like "{ORIGINAL_NAME}-new"
4. After the new cluster is up, go to the old cluster, edit it, and append "-old" to the name (it can be anything but just to keep them straight).
5. After the rename is complete go back to the new cluster, edit it, and change the name to be exactly what the original name was.
6. After the cluster is up make sure you can connect to it correctly and then delete the original cluster (the "-old" one).

CloudFormation hooks to the cluster by the cluster name.  So as long as the settings are identical to the original one then there should be no drift in the CF stack and it will be linked to the new cluster after the names are changed.